# In Python what is the code for F12 Keyboard press

Tags: python, selenium, automation, controller, keyboard

Platform: Python+selenium+pycharm

Requirement- Desktop - Open Chrome browser - Press <kbd>F12</kbd> key followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> together

Answer (score -1):

Install `sudo pip3 install keyboard` (in python3)
You can use:

```
import keyboard

keyboard.press_and_release('F12, ctrl+shift+m')
```

Comment: ctrl+shift+M - this is not getting performed

Comment: @TestingJustdial try it now, with lower "m". I edited.